# Why Can't I Call an SSH Terminal Command from Python?

Tags: python, shell, ssh, command-line, subprocess

I am trying to copy a file to my Raspberry pi through SSH and I would like to execute the windows terminal command from python, so I can automate it later. However, I get an error every time I try to execute it. The SSH command works as intended when I manually put it into the console but it does not work when I call it from this script. I have never called console commands in python before so I am trying to work with some other threads that I have found. What may I be doing wrong? I have also attempted to run `os.system` which did not return an error but also did not execute the command as it should. I am using Python 3.8.1. This is my script and the error, thanks for helping.

Code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['scp <text file path> pi@<IP>:here/'])
print ("done")
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script file path>.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.run(['scp <text file path>.txt pi@<IP>:here/'])
  File "<python file path>\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File <python file path>\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File <python file path>\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Edit: This is the error I get when I split the series of commands like this:

Code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['scp', '<text file path>.txt', 'pi@<IP>:here/'])
print ("done")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script file path>.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.run(['scp', '<text file path>.txt', 'pi@<IP>:here/'])
  File "<python file path>\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "<python file path>\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File <Python file path>\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Of course anything that I put in <> is to protect my information.

Edit: Run Method: [image]

Comment: Are you sure `<text file path>` exists?

Comment: just split the arguments: `['scp', '<text file path>', 'pi@<IP>:here/']`. Now it is looking for an executable with this long name, including spaces and args

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Yes I am sure that the file path exists as copying and pasting it directly into the command prompt works. I tried splitting it up but it I get the same error.

Comment: I agree with @Marat's comment. read the documentation of `subprocess` Arguments should normally be separated.
If you have any other errors afterwards, then please psot the exact error message / output

Comment: When I separate the arguments I get the exact same error except for any arguments that I split, they would also show up split. For example on the third line of the error message instead of saying `subprocess.run(['scp <text file path> pi@<IP>:here/'])` it would say `subprocess.run(['scp', '<text file path>', 'pi@<IP>:here/'])`

Comment: Please upload the updated stacktrace then. It is not supposed to work as a single string anyway

Comment: Could it be that it does not find `scp`? What happesn if you just run `scp`, without any arguments? If scp is found, it should write on stderr a short summary of the available scp options.

Comment: It is finding SCP when I do as you suggest. In fact, when I type the command into command prompt manually, it works as expected.

For splitting the arguments, I added the updated error messages to an edit in the question as the error was too long to add as a comment.

Comment: Is it an absolute path to the text file?

Comment: Yes, it starts directly from the C drive and has the path until desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone coming back to this post, the solution was to use a different method of running the script. I was using the default python IDLE which didn't seem to like it. Try running the script in your computer's console.

Answer (score 0):

Either drop the list and let the shell parse the string

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('scp <text file path> pi@<IP>:here/', shell=True)
print ("done")
```

or split your command into its constituent components yourself

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['scp', <text file path>, 'pi@<IP>:here/'])
print ("done")
```

As for your error, either `<text file path>` is an incorrect relative path (given the current working directory) or `scp` isn't in your `PATH`. It's not clear from the error message which file can't be found.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both of these. The first one had the same result as my other question and the second one gave the same error that I outlined in this question. I am not sure what it means in file not found as it runs fine through the command prompt.

Comment: How are you actually running the script? The working directory may be different, changing how the relative path resolves.

Comment: I made and edit at the end of the question showing how I am running it.

Comment: OK, the current working directory probably  isn't the directory that contains your script; it's what it inherits from the IDE you are using.

Comment: How would you recommend running it?